# Munn semigroup and their properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, inverse-semigroups

Some definition :

- Let $S$ be an inverse semigroup and $E$ be the set of all idempotents in $S$. Then $E$ form a semilattice under this relation
  $$e \leq f \; \; \text {iff} \; ef = fe = e$$
  Define a relation $ \huge{\mu}$ $= \{ (e,f) \in E \times E : Ee \cong Ef \}$, where $Ee$ is the principal ideal generated by $e$ in $E$ and define a set $T_{e,f}$ consist of all isomorphism from $Ee$ onto $Ef$ if $(e,f) \in \huge \mu$.
- Define $T_E = \underset{(e,f) \in \huge \mu}{\huge\cup} T_{e,f}$ which form a 
  inverse semigroup under the composition.
- A semigroup $S$ is said to be bisimple if $S$ has only one $\mathcal D$- class, where $\mathcal D$ is a Green's relation.
- A subsemigroup $T$ of $T_E$ is said to be transitive if $\forall e,f \in E,$
  $$ T \cap T_{e,f} \neq \phi$$

My question is

> > Suppose $T_E$ is bisimple semigroup. Is it true that ever subsemigroup $T$ of $T_E$ is transitve.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How do you define the composition of an element of $T_{e_1,f_1}$ with an element of $T_{e_2,f_2}$ ?

Comment: Suppose $\alpha \in T_{e_1, f_1}, \beta \in T_{e_2, f_2}$, then  dom $\alpha \beta = [$ im $\alpha \cap$dom $\beta] \alpha^{-1} = [ Ef_1 \cap Ee_2]\alpha^{-1} = (Ef_1e_2)\alpha^{-1}$. Since $E_{f_1e_2}$ is an ideal contained in $Ef_1$ and $\alpha^{-1} \in T_{f_1, e_1}$, so  [ im $\alpha \cap$dom $\beta] \alpha^{-1}$ is an ideal contained in $Ee_1$ and it denoted by $Ee$. Similarly im$\alpha \beta$ = [im $\alpha \cap$dom $\beta] \beta$ is a principal ideal contained in $Ef_2$ and it is denoted by $Ef$. Thus $\alpha \beta \in T_{e,f}$

Comment: Pretty sure T_E is not bisimple, did you mean transitive?

Comment: @James : You are right, $T_e$ is not bisimple. This is bisimple if $\huge{\mu}$ is uniform semilattice. This is my mistake, sorry for this, I will edit it.